# How do I add randomly generated characters to a string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, random

I'm trying to create a program that solves the Countdown words game which involves asking for a proportion of vowels and consonants. I want to add random characters to a string that will be passed to a permutation function.

When I run the following program and select "C" I get the error "l buffer is too small && 0 c" and the program crashes.

Typing "V" will give the error "Invalid!EIOU" without crashing.

How can I create this random string with vowel and consonant amounts dictated by the user's input?

Should this be done as an array instead?

```
// April16Assignment.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const char * main() {

    char type, letters[10] = { };
    char vowels[6] = { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
    char consonants[21] = { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    int i, k, v, l, c;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("Vowel or consonant? (V/C)\n");
        scanf_s("%c", &type);

        if (type == 'V')
            for (k = 0; k<1; k++) {
                v = (rand() % 5);
                strcat_s(letters, &vowels[v]);

            }
        if (type == 'C')
            for (l = 0; l<1; l++) {
                c = (rand() % 21);
                strcat_s(letters, &consonants[c]);

            }
        else
            printf("Invalid!");
        break;
    }

    printf("%s", letters);
    return letters;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `main` returning a non integer value? By convention, `main` should always return an `int`, the value of which depends on whether your program was executed correctly.

Comment: is this a homework problem? if so, mention that explicitly

Comment: That looks more like a C++ program, and is using Microsoft's "secure" string functions. Ignoring that, the main problem is that `strcat_s` works with null-terminated strings, but you are passing a pointer to a single character in an array of characters (`vowel` or `consonent`), most of which are definitely not followed by a null-terminator. The `vowel` and `consonent` arrays as a whole do not contain null-terminated strings, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Your title and tag are C, but the file extension is cpp. Which language do you use?

Comment: @IanAbbott Actually `vowels` contains terminating null-character as the not explicitly initialized last element, while `consonants` doesn't.

Comment: @MikeCAT: So it does. I missed that!

Comment: In `strcat_s` you have omitted the length argument. Please [read the man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx) and enable compiler warnings. Similarly for `scanf_s` there must be a length argument for each format specifier of type `%c` or `%s`.

Comment: the `else` is only for the last `if`, so if you enter `'V'`, it will also print `"Invalid!"`. Why do you have a `for` loop if you `break;` it at the first iteration?

Answer (score 1):

- The `scanf_s` will read newline characters if you enter them. Add a space *before* `%c` to have the function skip them.
- Your usage of `strcat_s` seems strange. The function will take three arguments, but you are passing only two. In this case, you can just assign characters.
- `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` are for C++, not C, and they are not used here. remove them.
- Your type of `main()` looks weird.

Try this (sorry, I hate VC++ specific functions):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char type, letters[10] = { };
    char vowels[6] = { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
    char consonants[21] = { 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    int i, k, v, l, c;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("Vowel or consonant? (V/C)\n");
        scanf(" %c", &type);

        if (type == 'V')
            for (k = 0; k<1; k++) {
                v = (rand() % 5);
                letters[i] = vowels[v];

            }
        if (type == 'C')
            for (l = 0; l<1; l++) {
                c = (rand() % 21);
                letters[i] = consonants[c];

            }
        else
            printf("Invalid!");
        break;
    }

    printf("%s", letters);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the "Invalid!" option and added break; and that seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for the help!